# Authorize.Net issue with credit card Expiration Date

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am trying to do a CIM transaction using authorize.net but whenever i am entering the credit card expiration date in the specified format(YYYY-MM) I am getting an error showing the date field length is greater than the maximum value and the date shown in this result is by default appending the "DD" portion.

Please help me in getting the solution to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting that error and you see the -DD then you are inadvertently sending the expiration date with the -DD appended to the date. Echo the expiration date out just before you pass it to Authnet and see what it says. Somewhere you are either appending or not removing the -DD from that date.

Answer (score 2):

Echo it out to the screen, make sure that date is not 1,000 years in the past! :)